# how to pass array of objects as parameters on ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parameters

I have the following array object

```
[{"site":"88333","event":"TEST","event_window":"4th April - 4th April","monitoring_start":"10-Apr-2016","monitoring_end":"10-Apr-2016"}]
```

I am trying to pass on ajax post as key value. I can have multiple rows. I have tried `$.param(JSON.stringify(json_o))` and `$.param(json_o)`, which does not work

Example shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) looks like array object which I have done but does not work.

```
var params = JSON.stringify(json_o);
        console.log(params);
        $.ajax({
            url : '../../api/netcool/add-event',
            data : params,
            type: 'POST',
            error : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if(data.statusText != "abort")
                    console.log(data);
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you don't have to do anything, just send the objects as `data` in your `$.ajax` request.

Comment: not sure what you mean?

Comment: `$.ajax({ url : 'someurl', data : your_array[0] })`

Comment: I want to pass everything in array as I can have multiple sites

Comment: Then pass everything, you don't have to stringify or `$.param` anything, just send it

Comment: How the data needs to be encoded also depends on what the server expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
var params = [{"site":"88333","event":"TEST","event_window":"4th April - 4th April","monitoring_start":"10-Apr-2016","monitoring_end":"10-Apr-2016"}];
    console.log(params);
    $.ajax({
        url : '../../api/netcool/add-event',
        data : {params:params},
        type: 'POST',
        error : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if(data.statusText != "abort")
                console.log(data);
        },
        success : function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

And in ../../api/netcool/add-event method.. you can acccess the parameter by

```
print_r($_REQUEST['params'][0]);
echo $_REQUEST['params'][0]['site'];
```