# How to get the table of records using Jquery and send it to server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a table like below

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">Bill NO</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="Checkbox0" class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox">/td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>12-22-2014</td>
            <td>computer problem</td>
            <td>Invoice</td>
            <td class="ActualAmount">7689.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="Checkbox1" class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox">/td>
            <td>112</td>
            <td>12-22-2014</td>
            <td>Printer problem</td>
            <td>Invoice</td>
            <td class="ActualAmount">7689.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**I am trying to get the value of `BillNo`and `ActualAmount` if checkbox is selected on that row**

First I try to get the value of the row using this below code

```
alert('value = ' + $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1 .checkBoxClass input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("td").val())
```

**it alert** `value = undefined`

I am trying to get the value like this [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oss4neo6/2/)

Comment: how is that fiddle related to your code? note: `closest("td")` to the input is the `td` enclosing the input. You probably want it's next sibling instead

Comment: @Jaromandax No, I just tried whether it's showing the next value or not. But I want to get the 2nd and 6th td value only. Each row having 10 td, For making clear here i removed some of td element

Comment: right, but getting closest to the input will be the td enclosing the input, so that code you posted is completely inadequate

Comment: So what is the problem if you already have working snippet that does almost everything you need?

Comment: @dfsq I am trying to make an array like that snippet with my table record and pass it server through ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all rows that has that checkbox checked and save that values in an array of objects...

```
var values = [];

$('table#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1 input.checkBoxClass:checked').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
    values.push({ 'billno': $row.eq(1).text(), 'amount': $row.eq(5).text() });
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: @A.lglesias I hope your code is correct, but it doesn't alert anything when i do `alert(values)` after your code

Comment: `values` is an array of objects. To alert its value you can do `alert(JSON.stringify(values));`

Comment: @A.lglesias correct brother thanks, how should i pass through the ajax, what is the data type in ajax, and the datatype i should give in webmethod?

Comment: Here you have an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408465/how-to-pass-array-of-objects-as-parameters-on-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

try this in your alert message

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1  input[type='checkbox'].checkBoxClass:checked").parent().next().html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1 .checkBoxClass input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text()
```

will work for BillNo (but it should be better to add a class or a data-tag in your html for this column, as you did for actualAmount).

For actual Amount :

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1 .checkBoxClass input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").find("td.ActualAmount").text()
```